# How to change google-cloud-run continuous deploy to java version to 17 in buildpack?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I setup a gcp google-cloud-run Java and Spring Boot deployment using the `Continuously deploy from a repository` option as shown below.

[image]

This creates an inline Cloud Build trigger with using an inline configuration. I got it working but the Java version was set to Java 11 and this was a problem for SpringBoot 3.X.

My question is how can I change the inline Cloud Build configuration to use Java 17 instead of Java 11?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it working, sharing here.

First edit the Cloud Build trigger and open the editor

[image]

Then add the `GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION` argument to the buildpack as shown here: Be sure to save your changes.

[image]